# How to get better csv export in Netlogo and BehaviourSpace?

Tags: r, csv, time-series, export-to-csv, netlogo

I was reading the following two websites [about how to export csv data from Netlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22462168/netlogo-export-tableau-issues) and how to use the [time extension](https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/) by Colin Sheppard with its [times series functionality](https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/#time-series-tool). I have quite some time trying on how to get both things working together but do not know how to make it happen. Does somebody has any experience with the time extension and know how to put both together?

My idea is to have something like the export-all-plots function but with better csv output for later use in Gnu R (since the standard-output of Netlogo data in csv is very odd!).

Here is a copy and paste of both code snippets in question:

```
to write-csv [ #filename #items ]
;; #items is a list of the data (or headers!) to write.
if is-list? #items and not empty? #items
[ file-open #filename
;; quote non-numeric items
set #items map quote #items
;; print the items
;; if only one item, print it.
ifelse length #items = 1 [ file-print first #items ]
[file-print reduce [ (word ?1 "," ?2) ] #items]
;; close-up
file-close
]
end

to-report quote [ #thing ]
ifelse is-number? #thing
[ report #thing ]
[ report (word "\"" #thing "\"") ]
end
```

and this one:

```
extensions [ time ]

globals
[ 
  dt ;time in model
  time-series ;alibi variable
  time-series-file-name ;file name
]

to setup
  ca
  set dt time:anchor-to-ticks (time:create-with-format "1250" "YYYY") 1 "years" ;model start in year 1250
  time:anchor-schedule dt 1 "years" ;anchor time with schedule in model  
  set time-series-file-name "path/to/file.csv" ;set working file for time-series
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  export ;create tables for later use

  tick
end

to export
  set time-series time:ts-create ["item1" "item2"] ;create header of table
  time:ts-add-row time-series [] ;add data to time series
  time:ts-add-row time-series []
  time:ts-write time-series "path/to/file.csv" ;export time-series
end
```

Comment: You say "the standard-output of Netlogo data in csv is very odd". I would not say so, other than that you have to skip down to the header lines.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: On the same note as Alan, make sure you're using "table" output, not "spreadsheet" output.

Comment: Both of your comments have helped me to work around my temporary issue of importing the standard output to Gnu R, thank you very much. However, I would love to get the time-series export function running which is proposed [here](https://github.com/colinsheppard/time/#time-series-tool) with the time extension for Netlogo. Unfortunately, the documentation of this function is not clear enough to me to be able to implement it into my model yet.